# Jquery .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason this is non functional any help appreciated.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('select[name=materialSelect]').change(function(){
    alert("Changed");
   });
 });
</script>
<select name="materialSelect" id="materialSelect">
            <option value="-1">-----Select Material-----</option>
            <option value="0">Material</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Any errors in console???

Comment: put that code inside $(function(){});

Comment: Is JQuery on ? Maybe u 4got  it?

Comment: Shouldn't there be `<script>` tags around your javascript?

Comment: code is inside $(document).ready(function (){}); other JQuery functions are working as expected will continue to debug with console

Comment: Not sure why your using name selector when you have an id assigned to the select control.

Comment: Just do $("#materialSelect").change  if the element already exists. If not, use delegate, $("#materialSelect").on('change',function() . https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/bko2wsbu/

Comment: Are you included js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't have any issue, be careful that you've called your

```
$('select[name=materialSelect]').change(function(){
    alert("Changed");
 });
```

after which your html is loaded.

For sample binding the document load to a function that called your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a on change function of jquery available already you are binding it with body load which means your select doesn't exists when you call the function, you should do this :

```
$(document).on('change', '#materialSelect', function () {
alert('changed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine as long as the HTML element (on which you are binding the event) is present when the binding script is running.

To be on safe side, always bind to a parent element (`body` for example) which will delegate the event it to the child.

So, try this,

```
 $('body').on('change', 'select[name=materialSelect]', function(){
    alert("Changed");
 });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <select name="materialSelect" id="materialSelect">
        <option value="">-----Select Material-----</option>
        <option value="0">Material</option>
      </select>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select[name=materialSelect]').change(function(){
          alert("Changed");
        });
      });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you are declaring the script after html in your DOM, you don't need $(document).ready.

Comment: In some application,you have to do this. i face the same problem.

Comment: Nope, you never have to do it if your html is being loaded before your script.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd look into where jQuery is being loaded. jQuery needs to be loaded before any scripts that use it.

Incorrect:

```
<script>
    $('.something').change(...
</script>
<script src=""></script><!-- jquery -->
```

Correct:

```
<script src=""></script><!-- jquery -->
<script>
    $('.something').change(...
</script>
```

Secondly, you should be using some kind of document on ready function. This will ensure your HTML is rendered before applying your events (eg "onchange")

Correct:

```
<script src=""></script><!-- jquery -->
<script>
    $(function () {
        // DOM is now ready
        $('.something').change(...
    })
</script>
```